# Laravel subdomain authentication not working - 419 Error

Tags: laravel, authentication, session, subdomain

i got a common situation:

- *staging*.**domain.com** : a Laravel 10 application linked to **development** repository branch
- *production*.**domain.com** : the same Laravel 10 application linked to **main** repository branch

When i visit applications **XSRF-TOKEN** and session cookies are stored with the same domain **.domain.com** that generate a 419 Error when i try to login on the last application i visit.

Is there a solution to specify the full subdomain or resolve the issue in another way?? I also tried to specify SESSION_DOMAIN with sub domain but Laravel automatically add a dot at start of the string (ex. .staging.domain.com).

Ty.

1. Specify different sub-domain as SESSION_DOMAIN
2. Changed Session cookie path
3. use different SESSION_COOKIE name for applications

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.